# QAction doesn't show QMenu

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-designer

I'm creating my UI from Qt Designer and it generares this code:

```
toolBar = new QToolBar(MainWindow);
QIcon icon;
icon.addFile(QStringLiteral(":/main"), QSize(), QIcon::Normal, QIcon::Off);
MainWindow->addToolBar(Qt::TopToolBarArea, toolBar);
actionConvert = new QAction(MainWindow);
actionConvert->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("actionConvert"));
actionConvert->setIcon(icon);
toolBar->addAction(actionConvert);
```

Now, back in my frame code:

```
QMenu *menuAdd = new QMenu (this);
menuAdd->addAction (tr("&Files..."));
menuAdd->addAction (tr("&Directory..."));
ui->actionConvert->setMenu (menuAdd);
```

When I run the application I can see the qaction in the toolbar even the arrow pointing down, which indicates that there is a menu, but when I click it, the menu doesn't appear...any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be anything wrong with your example code.

It's possible that the reason you aren't seeing the menu is that you need to press and hold the button for a few seconds in order for the menu to appear. A single click will just execute the button's normal action.

See: [QToolButton::ToolButtonPopupMode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbutton.html#ToolButtonPopupMode-enum).

Comment: Right. Do this: `dynamic_cast<QToolButton*>(toolbar->widgetForAction(action))->setPopupMode(QToolButton::InstantPopup)`

Answer (score 0):

You should add menu with [menuBar()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#menuBar) method as in my case:

```
void MainWindow::ueInitMenu()
{
    this->ueSetCodeRegisterPlacesAction(new QAction(tr("Places"),
                                        this));
    this->ueCodeRegisterPlacesAction()->setShortcut(tr("Ctrl+P"));
    this->ueCodeRegisterPlacesAction()->setStatusTip(tr("Shows places code register"));

    connect(this->ueCodeRegisterPlacesAction(),
            SIGNAL(triggered()),
            this,
            SLOT(ueSlotShowPlacesView()));

    this->ueSetCodeRegisterMenu(this->menuBar()->addMenu(tr("Code register")));
    this->ueCodeRegisterMenu()->addAction(this->ueCodeRegisterPlacesAction());
}   // ueInitMenu
```

especialy the line:

this->ueSetCodeRegisterMenu(this->menuBar()->addMenu(tr("Code register")));
so in your case:

```
this->menuBar()->addMenu(tr("System menu");
```

and then add `actions`. Also take a look at [Menus Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-menus-example.html).